# How to get list of dependencies of non-installed RPM package?

Tags: linux, rpm, yum, dependencies

`apt-cache show <package>` shows also it's dependencies.

`yum info <package>` does not show dependencies, but it obviously know them.

How to ask yum for dependencies of specified package?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

yum doesn't have that capability. Use the `repoquery` tool from the `yum-utils` package instead.

```
repoquery --requires <package>
```

OR to also see which additional RPM packages are needed to satisfy the dependencies, use --resolve

```
repoquery --requires --resolve <package>
```

Comment: How would I do the same if I have a local rpm file?

Comment: Maybe extract the control file from rpm package and look into it?

Comment: If you have it downloaded then you use `rpm -qp --requires <package file>`.

Comment: If you use RHN, you need to add --plugins to the call to repoquery. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433843/why-is-repoquery-not-listing-the-files-in-a-package

Comment: What does `--resolve` actually do? Running `repoquery --requires --resolve` on a package that is already installed should return an empty list right, since all dependencies are already satisfied? When I tried it on a package that is already installed, I got a few listed, including *itself* (all of these are already installed).

Comment: I don't think it's true that yum can't do this.  See the answer below

Comment: You have to be very careful about this though, the `Requires` and `Provides` don't always exactly match package names, and `--resolve` will list every possible provider.If you do `dnf repoquery --requires --resolve curl` for example, you'll get both `libcurl` and `libcurl-minimal` as results because both are options to satisfy the requirement for a `libcurl >= {version}`.

Answer (score 61):

Use `deplist` command,

```
yum deplist <package>
```

From yum's manual:

> Produces a list of all dependencies and what packages provide those dependencies for the given packages.

#### Update for dnf

To do the same thing with dnf, we can do

```
dnf repoquery --requires <package>
```

As `man yum2dnf` said:

> Alternative to Yum **deplist** command to  find  out  dependencies  of  the
>          package is **dnf repoquery --requires** using repoquery plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will return a list of all possible providers of each dependency, which can end up returning many hundreds or thousands of lines, instead of a simple list of the names of dependent packages.

Answer (score 15):

If you have a local RPM, you can get a list of dependencies via:

```
rpm -qpR mediawiki-1.4rc1-4.i586.rpm
```

Comment: Works for URLs too.

Comment: if you ommit -q then you can query your configured repos: rpm -qR graphviz lists all the dependencies for me

Answer (score 4):

If you need the list of packages needed, use:

dnf repoquery --requires --resolve`

In the case of firefox, by running:

`sudo dnf repoquery --requires --resolve firefox`

I've got the ouput:

`Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:00 ago on Wed 13 Dec 2017 21:41:47 GMT.
atk-0:2.26.1-1.fc27.x86_64
bash-0:4.4.12-12.fc27.x86_64
cairo-0:1.15.8-1.fc27.x86_64
cairo-gobject-0:1.15.8-1.fc27.x86_64
dbus-glib-0:0.108-4.fc27.x86_64
dbus-libs-1:1.12.0-1.fc27.x86_64
fontconfig-0:2.12.6-4.fc27.x86_64
freetype-0:2.8-6.fc27.x86_64
freetype-freeworld-0:2.8-4.fc27.x86_64
gdk-pixbuf2-0:2.36.11-1.fc27.x86_64
glib2-0:2.54.2-1.fc27.x86_64
glibc-0:2.26-16.fc27.i686
glibc-0:2.26-16.fc27.x86_64
gtk2-0:2.24.31-6.fc27.x86_64
gtk3-0:3.22.26-1.fc27.x86_64
hunspell-0:1.5.4-4.fc27.x86_64
libX11-0:1.6.5-4.fc27.x86_64
libX11-xcb-0:1.6.5-4.fc27.x86_64
libXcomposite-0:0.4.4-11.fc27.x86_64
libXdamage-0:1.1.4-11.fc27.x86_64
libXext-0:1.3.3-7.fc27.x86_64
libXfixes-0:5.0.3-4.fc27.x86_64
libXrender-0:0.9.10-4.fc27.x86_64
libXt-0:1.1.5-6.fc27.x86_64
libffi-0:3.1-14.fc27.x86_64
libgcc-0:7.2.1-2.fc27.x86_64
libjpeg-turbo-0:1.5.1-4.fc27.x86_64
libstdc++-0:7.2.1-2.fc27.x86_64
libvpx-0:1.6.1-4.fc27.x86_64
libxcb-0:1.12-5.fc27.x86_64
mozilla-filesystem-0:1.9-17.fc27.x86_64
nspr-0:4.17.0-1.fc27.i686
nspr-0:4.17.0-1.fc27.x86_64
nss-0:3.34.0-1.0.fc27.i686
nss-0:3.34.0-1.0.fc27.x86_64
nss-util-0:3.34.0-1.0.fc27.x86_64
p11-kit-trust-0:0.23.8-1.fc27.i686
p11-kit-trust-0:0.23.9-2.fc27.x86_64
pango-0:1.40.14-1.fc27.x86_64
startup-notification-0:0.12-14.fc27.x86_64
u2f-hidraw-policy-0:1.0.2-5.fc27.x86_64
zlib-0:1.2.11-4.fc27.x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install a package *and* it's dependencies via yum, try the localinstall option instead if install. The `localinstall` install a package and finds any dependencies and downloads them:

```
$ yum -y localinstall <package>
```

I am no yum guru but this works fine for me, makes it easy to install including dependencies :-)